# Strategy to choose maximum number from an unknown array of n numbers, examining one at a time

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, estimation, sampling, ranking

Suppose you have an array of n normally distributed numbers whose values are initially unknown(and the probability parameters are unknown too).
You must choose one number and you want it to have maximum value.

You examine the numbers one number at a time.
You may only choose a number right after it is examined(that is we learn it's value) and before the next number is examined. What strategy would you use to maximize the expected value of chosen number?

My intuition and thinking:.
We can use numbers seen so far to estimate the distribution. We can than calculate the expected value of the maximum number in the rest of the list and if it is less than the current number we will take the current number. First of all is my thinking at all correct? And second of all can someone help me with the actual calculations because I have only taken one course in undergraduate probability so far. Thank you!

Comment: Just to confirm: the numbers are independent and identically distributed from the same normal distribution with unknown parameters?

Comment: @angryavian Correct.

Comment: Do you know the size of the array?

Comment: @frank . Yes we know the size in advance.

Comment: This is *very* like the [secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem), except you have additional information about the distribution of candidate quality (you state that it's normally distributed), not just their rank-order among the ones seen to date, so presumably there's a considerably better stopping strategy than for the secretary problem. This knowledge is useful since if you don't outperform it, you must have made an error.